# Is it possible to register an URI scheme using python?

Tags: python, uri, url-scheme

I'm trying to develop an Sublime Text 2 extension for listening for URI schemes. The API is python based. I wonder if it is possible to register an URI scheme listener for this extension? It should listen on subl://somfile?row=3&col=4

Forgot to mention that the solution should be suited for MAC OSX

Comment: i don't exactly understand what you're trying to do, but it seems you should look at how to implement your own [protocol handler](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#basehandler-objects)? (take this [finger-protocol implementation](https://github.com/wwaites/pyfinger/blob/master/pyfinger/fingerurl.py) as an example)

Comment: Yes I try to implement a protocol handler. But the main problem is how I can register that handler for mac OSX using python? I think it is done during installation in Objective-C